# Bluetooth on/off status in application with respect to Control Panel of iPhone

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an BLE interacting app where the iPhone application acts as a Central Manager & BLE accessory acts as a Peripheral.

Control Panel in iPhone shows Bluetooth On indicator. But app indicates bluetooth of iPhone is off.

Until iOS 10 this issue was not present. I am facing this issue since 11.x releases. Apple documentation states that Bluetooth related issues are resolved around 11.2.x releases. Currently iOS version is 11.4.1.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"ABC", CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @NO}];

NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"XYZ"]];
            NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @NO};
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options: options];
```

Any kind of help would be good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must not initiate any Bluetooth operations until you receive a `.poweredOn` state in `didUpdateState`

Comment: But that's where my issue lies. Though the state seen in iPhone's control panel is poweredOn, app states its poweredOff.

Comment: Are you getting an "API Misuse" error?  Is the code you have shown above exactly what you have in your app - ie, you are initiating the scan immediately after creating the `CBCentralManager`?

Comment: I will check for 'API Misuse' warnings. It does not happen each time. 
No, I check for state then initiate the scan.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show your *actual code*.  It is difficult to help otherwise.